# top 1 first_value() based on two criteria

Tags: sql-server

I'm  still new at mssqlserver, i need to get the first order for the same customer made order in certain period based on the brand name and customer_id I used first_value() as sub query with top 1 however i got only the first value based on the brand regardless the customer id

what i got

| Data | Customer_ID | Brand | first_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1649104 | PH | 2020-09-26 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1306498 | PH | 2020-09-26 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1290371 | PH | 2020-09-26 |
| 2022-01-01 | 456756 | TB | 2020-11-09 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1823713 | TB | 2020-11-09 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2178025 | BK | 2020-08-12 |
| 2022-01-01 | 216435 | BK | 2020-08-12 |
| 2022-01-01 | 19031 | BK | 2020-08-12 |
| 2022-01-01 | 438095 | BK | 2020-08-12 |

the code I used

```
SELECT Data , Brand  ,  Customer_ID  ,
(select  top 1 first_value(H.Data) over (partition by Customer_ID , Brand order by H.Data ASC) 
from ORDER H
where h.Customer_ID = Customer_ID and H.Brand = Brand 
) as firts_order
from ORDER
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_SOURCE SRC ON SRC.SRC_ID = ORDR_SOURCE

WHERE SRC_NAME IN ('SR 1' , 'SR 2') and DATE  = '2022-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after working around I have found a more efficient solution for me using min() Instead of the first_value()

SELECT H.Data , H.Brand  ,  H.Customer_ID  ,  O.Data
from ORDER H
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_SOURCE SRC ON SRC.SRC_ID = H.ORDR_SOURCE
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
select min(Data) AS Data, Brand,  Customer_ID
from ORDER
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_SOURCE  ON SRC_ID = ORDR_SOURCE
WHERE SRC_NAME IN ('SR 1' , 'SR 2')
GROUP by Brand,  Customer_ID )
AS O
ON  H.Brand  = O.Brand AND H.Customer_ID = O.Customer_ID
WHERE SRC_NAME IN ('SR 1' , 'SR 2') and DATE  = '2022-01-01'

Answer (score 0):

I've not used that `first_value()` window function before, but my bet is that you don't need a subquery. Instead:

```
SELECT Data, 
   Brand,  
   Customer_ID, 
   FIRST_VALUE(Data) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID, Brand ORDER BY Data) as first_order
FROM ORDER
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_SOURCE SRC ON SRC.SRC_ID = ORDR_SOURCE
WHERE SRC_NAME IN ('SR 1' , 'SR 2') AND DATE  = '2022-01-01'
```

Alternatively you *could* use a correlated subquery INSTEAD. You don't need to combine this with a window function. Although, I wouldn't recommend it since the window function route would be quicker.

```
SELECT Data , Brand  ,  Customer_ID  ,
  (
    select top 1 H.data
    from ORDER H
    where H.Customer_ID = O.Customer_ID 
        and H.Brand = O.Brand 
    ORDER BY H.Data ASC
  ) as first_order
from ORDER O
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_SOURCE SRC ON SRC.SRC_ID = ORDR_SOURCE    
WHERE SRC_NAME IN ('SR 1' , 'SR 2') and DATE  = '2022-01-01'
```

Comment: thanks for the support, the first query is good but I need the first_order that older than the date in the where before jan 2022 , the second query also get one value in first_order not for each customer id per brand

Comment: For that first one, should the query have in the WHERE clause `WHERE data < '2022-01-01'`?

Comment: it will get both date orders and the date of the first order before Jan, what I need order date in Jan and the first order of the same customer and same brand before Jan